How should i set my .json files in vscode?
How should i set my .JSON files in my c++ directory:

task.JSON
launch.JSON
c_cpp_properties.JSON
settings.JSON

I'm using GCC.
My current configurations are:
1. launch.JSON

{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}


2. c_cpp_properties.JSON


{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}

# **settings.JSON**
{
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "gdb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcBatchPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/VR_NR/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useMsvc": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warnings": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Wshadow",
    "-Wformat=2",
    "-Wcast-align",
    "-Wconversion",
    "-Wsign-conversion",
    "-Wnull-dereference"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcWarnings": [
    "/W4",
    "/permissive-",
    "/w14242",
    "/w14287",
    "/w14296",
    "/w14311",
    "/w14826",
    "/w44062",
    "/w44242",
    "/w14905",
    "/w14906",
    "/w14263",
    "/w44265",
    "/w14928"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.enableWarnings": true,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warningsAsError": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.linkerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includeSearch": [
    "*",
    "**/*"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.excludeSearch": [
    "**/build",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.*",
    "**/.*/**",
    "**/.vscode",
    "**/.vscode/**"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useAddressSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useUndefinedSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLeakSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.showCompilationTime": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLinkTimeOptimization": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcSecureNoWarnings": false
}

3. settings.JSON
{
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "gdb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcBatchPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/VR_NR/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useMsvc": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warnings": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Wshadow",
    "-Wformat=2",
    "-Wcast-align",
    "-Wconversion",
    "-Wsign-conversion",
    "-Wnull-dereference"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcWarnings": [
    "/W4",
    "/permissive-",
    "/w14242",
    "/w14287",
    "/w14296",
    "/w14311",
    "/w14826",
    "/w44062",
    "/w44242",
    "/w14905",
    "/w14906",
    "/w14263",
    "/w44265",
    "/w14928"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.enableWarnings": true,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warningsAsError": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.linkerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includeSearch": [
    "*",
    "**/*"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.excludeSearch": [
    "**/build",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.*",
    "**/.*/**",
    "**/.vscode",
    "**/.vscode/**"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useAddressSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useUndefinedSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLeakSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.showCompilationTime": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLinkTimeOptimization": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcSecureNoWarnings": false
}

please also give configuration for tasks.JSON
Maybe it has something to do about the version:
gcc version - gcc (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0
g++ version - g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0
gdb version - GNU gdb (GDB) 15.1
this error keeps showing when i run a program:
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\c++ programs\dsa mosh> cd "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\c++ programs\dsa mosh\" ; if ($?) { g++ pointers.cpp -o pointers } ; if ($?) { .\pointers }
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status

And also, how do you set it for a c directory ?
I spend the whole day reading vscode documentation and scouring the internet.
Please be nice, this is the second time i am asking a question (Last time I asked a question it was deleted).

Why not use Microsoft Visual Studio Community, working with default settings right after installation of the desktop development component, and forget visual studio code like a bad dream.

what is the full text of the compiler output? If you're compiling C++ code you need to use g++ not gcc. Please show a [mre]

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78477174/11107541 ?

@3CxEZiVlQ    I would really like to know what's going on behind the scenes 'professor'

@AlanBirtles what do you mean by 'comiler output' ? This is  the full error message displayed in the terminal.

I would really like to know what's going on behind the scenes 'professor The scene behind the compiler work. This does not depends on compilers. Choose a more comfortable tool, it's not mandatory to repeat your professor choice.

@starball But this does not have an answer

I very much doubt that is the full output of the compiler, even if you're using code runner (which is a bad idea) it should give you more feedback than that

@Mairon - You are not really learning about the "behind the scenes", but how to set up a hard-to-configure text editor to look like an IDE, and to make it use Linux tools on Windows. The recommendation is usually to start with a pre-configured IDE, like Visual Studio Community, and look behind the screen later.

@BoP - I have heard that it uses a lot of resources and takes time to launch. I don't feel like I need an ide now, have to get comfortable with programming.

@AlanBirtles - I have updated the error. Please take a look.

Ok, looks like starbull was right, your compiler is broken. I'd guess that you have incompatible dlls on your path

@Marion - I argue that you are not learning programming in C++ right now, but instead you learn about JSON, how to configure software (that could have a default setup that just works), and how running Linux tools on Windows have their own peculiarities. Sure, you get some experience here, but it is not about C++.

@Marion - So again, one option is Visual Studio Community, which just works right out of the box - it even writes you the first "Hello World"-program, so you can verify that it works. Sure, it might use 10 GB or more of your disk, but disk space is cheap. And at least on my (6 year old) machine it starts in 5 seconds flat. Your choice.
